# Should I init MySQL every time I want to run a query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a little (and stupid) problem: I'm building a PHP application using mysqli and a MySQL server. When the application is loaded, a variable called $database is initialized using

```
$database = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

This, of course, works perfectly. If I create an statement to do a query:

```
$stmt = $database->prepare('SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE a = ?');
```

This still works. But, if I try to create another statement without closing the previous one, sometimes works, and sometimes now. The error I get when the creation of the statement fails is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

And my question is: why? What should I do, open a connection (new mysql(...)) every time I want to create a new statement (and I have another open)?

**Example**

```
$stmt = $database->prepare('SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE a = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $aValue);
$stmt->execute();
/* do some other operations, without closing $stmt */
$stmt2 = $database->prepare('INSERT INTO table2 (e, f) VALUES (? ,?)');
// Now, $stmt2 isn't initialized, so when the next line is run, the app fails
$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $someValue, $anotherValue);
```

If, before the

```
$stmt2 = $database->prepare('INSERT INTO table2 (e, f) VALUES (? ,?)');
```

I add a simple

```
$stmt->close();
```

All works without any problems. So, what is the problem?

Comment: This should work fine.  I've done this before.  Maybe the error is with the query you are preparing.  Try to see if there are nay errors.  Add this after `$stmt2 = $database->prepare`: `if($stmt2 === FALSE){ die($database->error); }`

Comment: Another thing to try is to prepare both queries before executing either of them.

Comment: Rocket: The error I get is: 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'

Comment: Try my suggestion of preparing all the queries before either of them are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run another query until you have fetched all the results from the previous.  Otherwise you will have to make a separate connection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to bind_param & execute ? :

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $string);
$stmt->execute();
//etc..
```

OR

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $int);
$stmt->execute();
//etc..
```

IF you want multiple queries : check out `multi_query`

Comment: Yes, I use bind_param and execute. The problem isn't this.